# Twitter Typeahead not working with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I can't manage to make this bootply work.
It consists of a bootstrap modal with a form containing two input fields in which I'd like to use typeahead. the second input field is also based on bootstrap-tagsinput which means the typeahead should aid in finding tags.

http://www.bootply.com/QdjImYdrJY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your bootply and made it to work : http://www.bootply.com/5tVniXhbBg

You had two issues :

- First one, your scripts load asynchronously, so you have to wait for them to be loaded to use their functions (i.e tagsinput and typeahead)

  `$.getScript(
       'myscript' , 
        function () { 
            // Callback function, 
            // Here you can use what the script you loaded provides.
        }
  );`
- Second one, you don't have to put the `data-role="tagsinput"` manually, it will be added by the plugin. If you specify it, the plugin won't process it as it thinks it already processed it!

Hope this helps,